# Getting null pointer exception that I can't figure out

Tags: java

I have been working on this issue for a while. I keep getting a null pointer exception on the following function, the myProfile variable is a reference to another class that had been declared at the beginning as private UserProfile myProfile, where UserProfile is the original class, I believe that is where I'm running into the problem.:

```
public void saveProfile()
{
    if ((myProfile!=(null)) && !(myProfile.getName().isEmpty()))
    {
        profiles.put(myProfile.getName(), myProfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the profiles variable null? You need to use `System.out.println(...)` debug code generously when trying to figure this out. i.e., try `System.out.println("profiles is null? " + (profiles == null));`

Answer (score 3):

If `myProfile` is not `null` as you said, check what `myProfile.getName()` is returning using debugger. If it returns null, then you cannot call `isEmpty` on a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere there's a dot (`.`), you have a possibility of a null pointer exception. For example, you check that `myProfile` is not null, but you don't check whether `myProfile.getName()` is not null before attempting to do an `.isEmpty()` on it.

Likewise, if `profiles` is null, you'll get a null pointer exception when calling `.put()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

modify your code as follows. It wont cause an exception

```
public void saveProfile(){
    if ((myProfile!=null) && (myProfile.getName() != null) &&!(myProfile.getName().isEmpty())){
        profiles.put(myProfile.getName(), myProfile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void saveProfile()
{
  if (myProfile!=null && myProfile.getName()!=null && !myProfile.getName().isEmpty())
  {
    if(profiles==null)
      profiles = makeAnInstanceOfProfiles();

    profiles.put(myProfile.getName(), myProfile);
  }
}
```

With test code (run with assertion enabled):

```
public void saveProfile()
{
  assert(myProfile!=null):"null at myprofile";
  assert(myProfile.getName()!=null):"null at myprofile/getName";
  assert(profiles!=null) : "profiles is null";

  if (myProfile!=null && myProfile.getName()!=null && !myProfile.getName().isEmpty())
  {
    if(profiles==null)
      profiles = makeAnInstanceOfProfiles();

    profiles.put(myProfile.getName(), myProfile);
  }
}
```